# Why is same-document reference in SVG affected by HTML <base> tag?

Tags: svg, uri, fragment-identifier

I have an HTML page with a `<base>` tag, also containing SVG. Same-document references such as the below within the SVG then fail:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://my/server/basedir">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg>
      <g>
        <path d="M100,100 L150,150" id="path"/>
        <text>
          <textpath xlink:href="#path"/>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `xlink:href="#path"` reference fails to resolve. This works fine without the HTML `base` element. It also works if I replace the `href` attribute on the `textpath` element with an absolute IRI followed by the fragment identifier.

It seems to me that SVG should treat same-document IRI's differently and independent of the HTML `base`. In http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/#same-document it says "Dereferencing of same-document references is handled specially.", although granted that's in the context of `xml:base`. By the way, I played with putting an `xml:base` on the `svg` element in hopes of overriding the HTML `base` setting for couldn't figure out how to make that work.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: without `xml:base`**

Works in IE(Edge),Chrome, but not Firefox.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://my/server/basedir">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <g>
        <path d="M100,100 L150,150" id="path"/>
        <text>
          <textpath xlink:href="#path">Hello</textpath>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Case 2: with `xml:base`**

Works in IE(Edge),Chrome, Firefox.

If this page url is `http://my/thisfile.htm` then set `xml:base="http://my/thisfile.htm"` on the svg tag or textpath tag.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://my/server/basedir">
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg width="300" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xml:base="http://my/thisfile.htm">
      <g>
        <path d="M100,100 L150,150" id="path"/>
        <text>
          <textpath xlink:href="#path">Hello</textpath>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `xml:base` is deprecated https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341854